# Problem with pyLoad: Fatal Python error: Couldn't create autoTLSkey mapping

Tags: python, django

After running pyload on my Debian 3.14 shared server, I get this error:
Fatal Python error: Couldn't create autoTLSkey mapping

Here is the full log:

```
python pyLoadCore.py
17.01.2017 22:20:56 INFO Starting pyLoad 0.4.9
17.01.2017 22:20:56 INFO Using home directory: /home/pyload/settings
17.01.2017 22:20:56 INFO Checksum: Checksum validation is disabled in general configuration
17.01.2017 22:20:56 INFO ExtractArchive: No UnRar installed
17.01.2017 22:20:56 INFO ExtractArchive: Activated UnZip
17.01.2017 22:20:56 INFO Activated plugins: BypassCaptcha, CaptchaTrader, Checksum, ClickAndLoad, ExternalScripts, ExtractArchive, ImageTyperz, LinkdecrypterCom, UnSkipOnFail, UpdateManager, XFileSharingPro
17.01.2017 22:20:56 INFO Deactivate plugins: AlldebridCom, Captcha9kw, CaptchaBrotherhood, DeathByCaptcha, DownloadScheduler, EasybytezCom, Ev0InFetcher, ExpertDecoders, HotFolder, IRCInterface, MergeFiles, MultiHome, MultishareCz, Premium4Me, PremiumizeMe, RealdebridCom, RehostTo, XMPPInterface, ZeveraCom
17.01.2017 22:20:56 INFO Downloadtime: True
17.01.2017 22:20:56 INFO Starting ThriftBackend: 0.0.0.0:7227
17.01.2017 22:20:56 INFO Starting builtin webserver: 0.0.0.0:8000
17.01.2017 22:20:56 INFO Free space: 783.60 GiB
17.01.2017 22:20:56 INFO Activating Accounts...
17.01.2017 22:20:56 INFO Activating Plugins...
17.01.2017 22:20:56 ERROR LinkdecrypterCom: Crypter list not found
17.01.2017 22:20:57 INFO pyLoad is up and running Fatal Python error: Couldn't create autoTLSkey mapping Aborted
```

Apparently it's due to low memory but I can't find a way how to increase it. Since pyLoad is written in Django, apparently it should be done with uWSGI but I can't seem to find how.

I've tried issuing their Github page but it doesn't seem to go anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: 1. What does this have to do with U&L? 
2. From where did you get that this is due to low memory? The error quite clearly states `ERROR LinkdecrypterCom: Crypter list not found` which is answered here https://github.com/pyload/pyload/issues/859

Comment: Because I get this error in my Linux box and I also said that I know it's not 100% related here but I don't know anywhere better to ask it.

All my searches re the last error are talking about low memory error.

The fix you mentioned is very old and current code is far different now from that to apply those changes.

Comment: This should be on StackOverflow. U&L is for questions that are about U&L, not questions about programming in U&L. You can ask a moderator to migrate this, or delete this and ask separately on StackOverflow.

Comment: If you asking as a *user* of this software (say, as a sysadmin trying to download and install something), then it's probably on-topic here. If you're asking as a programmer using it as a tool to build your own software, then you indeed want [so].